# Angular Auxiliary Routing with IIS

Tags: angular, azure, iis, angular2-routing, angular-auxiliary-routes

We are using auxiliary routing `http://example.com/path(x:y/1/1)` and are hosting the application in Azure on an app service.  Every-time we refresh a page that uses an auxiliary route, or direct navigate to it, IIS gives the error "**A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:)**"

Other than allowing the `:` by setting `<httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="&lt;,&gt;,%,&amp;,\,?" />`, does anyone have any other solution for this?

Comment: How about [setting `validateRequest` attribute to false](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/whitepapers/request-validation#disabling-request-validation-for-your-application)?

Comment: This is basically the same as allowing the `:` to be passed through.